# How to decode multiple-digit gamma codes and get the gap sequence?

Tags: algorithms, data-compression, coding-theory, information-retrieval

How to decode gamma code ($\gamma$ code):

```
1110001110101011111101101111011
```

and get the gap sequence?

Detailed information about Gamma codes ($\gamma$ codes) with a brief example of decoding can be found [here](http://nlp.stanford.edu/IR-book/html/htmledition/gamma-codes-1.html).

But in their example there is only one case when gamma code ($\gamma$ code) consists of one digit only, how to deal with multiple digits binary string?

Comment: What research have you done?  P.S. I don't think this has anything to do with natural language processing...

Comment: This question is published as an exercise in the Stanford's book «[Introduction to Information Retrieval](http://www-nlp.stanford.edu/IR-book/)», in chapter #5, «Index Compression». And as I understand, NLP and IR have a common base. Thus, relevant tags — NLP and IR and if NLP-tag is, probably, not so relevant here, but IR-tag is really actual.

Comment: Regarding to research, I googled for it and what I found is a lot of slides describing what is index compression and giving  the same example I can see in the book with encoding/decoding the single number «13», but here I'm asking to decode a binary string with multiple numbers.

Comment: @Gilles, I'm agree with you, but just here I got the correct and practical answer I expected to receive from the beginning. So, the best solution will be to repost Amit's answer to the opened CS thread and close/delete the question here.

Comment: @Mike The answer that solves your concrete problem at hand *for you* is not always best at helping you *understand*.

Comment: @Mike We're not here to solve your homework. We're here to help you and others understand how to solve this and similar homework, and hopefully even help you and others use these concepts in real life. Homework is just a tool to help you learn, the real goal is future applications.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus, it was not a homework, I'm reading the book independently and trying to understand and solve the problems, offered by the book, which is not always user-friendly, especially for a newcomers in the subject. Thus, sometimes it is easier, IMHO, to perform kind of reverse-engineering of solved issue in order to understand how the things are working. Anyway, thanks for the theoretical explanation, it is very important too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The above sequence it read as a concatination of 5 numbers:

You start from the left side, read the first unary code. It let's you know what is the length of the first number. The 2nd number starts right after the 1st, and you interpet it the same way.

1. First, read the first unary code, it is 1110 - so the first number
   is "1110:001", which is 9
2. The next unary code is right after this, and is: "110" - so the 2nd number is "110:10" which is 6
3. The next unary code is "10", and the 3rd number is "10:1", which is 3
4. The next unary code is "111110", and the 4th number is "111110:11011", which is 32+16+8+2+1=59
5. Next unary number is "110", which gives you the 5th and last number, which is "110:11", which is 7.

So, the decoding of the given gamma code is actually 9,6,3,59,7

Comment: Amit, thanks a lot for a quick and clear answer!

Answer (score 2):

When encoding several numbers in sequence, we simply concatenate the encodings of the individual numbers. The gamma code is an example of a prefix-free code: no codeword is a prefix of another codeword. Due to this property, the encoding of every string has a *unique* prefix which is a codeword; this prefix encodes the first number. After removing it, you continue to find the second number, and so on, until exhausting the string.

As an example, let's decode 000100000100. The only prefix forming a codeword is 0001000, encoding 8. Removing this, we are left with 00100, which encodes 4. So the complete decoded sequence is 8,4.

As an aside, the gamma code is *complete*, which means that almost every infinite string (in fact, every infinite string other than $0^\omega$) is the encoding of some infinite sequence of numbers.

Comment: How do you detect a *free prefix code* (FPC) in any given binary string? How did you decide that for the string «000100000100» FPC will be «0001000» (=8) and not, let say, «00010000»? Suppose, I found a FPC for my string. Now I have to to continue to «concatenate the encodings of the individual numbers», but how do I know where should I split the string on individual numbers?

Comment: @Mike The whole *set* of codes, that is *the encoding scheme*, is prefix-free. It's not a property of a single word, that would not make much sense.

Comment: @Raphael, OK, but stil, how should I detect this prefix-free and how to split the rest of the string on separate digits in order to perform their decoding?

Comment: @Mike There will be a unique prefix which belongs to the code. In your example, I couldn't have chosen 00010000 since it's not a codeword. You can find it by, for example, trying all prefixes. In the particular case of the $\gamma$ code, I'm sure you can think of something even simpler.

Comment: Note that this answer uses a different encoding then @amit's answer ( which uses [this](https://nlp.stanford.edu/IR-book/html/htmledition/gamma-codes-1.html) encoding), the encoding here reverses the ones and zeros. If I use the first encoding to decode this example you would get:
1,1,1,2,1,1,1,2